# Othonormal basis for $L^2$ space on square

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

What is an explicit orthonormal basis for $L^2(\gamma,ds)$ where $\gamma$ is the boundary of the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and $ds$ is the arc length?

To be more precise can we express our ONB in terms of orthogonal polynomials such as Legendre etc?